# When eching, i get error because of if

Tags: php

Im creating option with if, because if need that on load item would b selected by the current view. I dont need JS. I was trying to do this, but i get error because of if, i done everything right i think here it is:

```
echo ('<option value="?m=ticketsmith&ticket_company=' . $row['company_id'] . '&type='.$type.'"'. if ($show_uid == $row['company_id']) { echo ' selected="selected"';}'/>' . $row['company_id'].', ' . $row["company_name"]) ;
```

I hope you guys will help me. And here is error messege: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in

Comment: Issue is that you are trying to use a `if(){}` inside a echo (and even echo inside a echo). Which you can't.

Comment: you can make variable with all parts of your Option element, paste every part of string to that var and in the end just do echo $foobar; cause you cant do if statement in echo (you can eventually do _($foobar==true)? 'true' : 'false'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo ('<option value="?m=ticketsmith&ticket_company=' . $row['company_id'] . '&type='.$type.'"'.  ($show_uid == $row['company_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) . '/>' . $row['company_id'].', ' . $row["company_name"]) ;
```

The change was this

```
if ($show_uid == $row['company_id']) { echo ' selected="selected"';}
```

to this

```
($show_uid == $row['company_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '' )
```

Comment: i get  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' in  ?

Comment: I've edited the above, should work now.

Comment: Thanx forgot to mark answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use echo inside echo.

Try following:

```
$isSelected = '';

if ($show_uid == $row['company_id']) {
    $isSelected = ' selected="selected"';
}

echo ('<option value="?m=ticketsmith&ticket_company=' . $row['company_id'] . '&type='.$type.'"'. $isSelected '/>' . $row['company_id'].', ' . $row["company_name"]);
```

Hope this helps!!